# Solving Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solving Partial Differential Equation  $u_{xyy} (x,y,z) = 2 \sin x $

---

Is this correct?

$$ \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial y \, \partial y \, \partial x} (x,y,z) = 2 \sin x $$

Integrate respect to y

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial y \, \partial x} (x,y,z) = 2y \sin x + f(x) $$

Integrate respect to y

$$ \frac{\partial u}{ \partial x} (x,y,z) = y^2 \sin x + yf(x) + g(x) $$

Integrate respect to x
$$ u(x,y,z) = -y^2 \cos x + yF(x) + G(x) + h(y) ;\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x) = f(x),\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x} G(x) = g(x) $$

Comment: Why aren't $f$ and $g$ functions of both $x$ and $z$?

Comment: so.., after the first integration, it should be $f(x,z)$ and in second integration $g(x,z)$, right? 
*I'm a bit confused integrating in this form.. *

and in the last integration, is it correct $h(y)$? or it should be $h(y,z)$

Comment: Yes. The last integration should add a function of $y, z$.

Comment: wait.., if it is $f(x,z)$ then what's the result if I integrate $yf(x,z)$ respect to $x$ ?

Comment: Integrating $y f(x,z)$ with respect to $x$ will give you $y F(x,z) + G(y,z)$ for some functions $F$ and $G$, where $\partial f/\partial x = F$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = F $ or $\frac{\partial F }{\partial x} = f $ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$
u_{xyy} = 2\sin x \\
u_{xy} = 2y\sin x + f(x,z)\\
u_x = y^2 \sin x + yf(x,z) + g(x,z) \\
u = -y^2 \cos x + yF(x,z) + G(x,z) + H(y,z)
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are completely arbitrary functions ($F \in C^1$).

Comment: at the second integration, why there is no constant if integration?
isn't should be $ \frac{\partial u}{ \partial x} (x,y,z) = y^2 \sin x + yf(x) + g(x,z) $

Comment: It should, of course. My bad